# More elegant way to remove variable input from function

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have this function:

```
def generate(offset:int=None) :
    unique_id = ''.join(random.choices(ID_CHARACTERS, k=7))
    return f'{unique_id}.{offset}'
```

However I want a more elegant solution, to not use an input variable, but I want to assure a number every time a unique ID is created.Any suggestions?

Comment: Note, as an aside, `offset:int=None` is a lie! You are assigning `None` to `offset` in the case where `generate()` is called with no argument, so this should be `def generate(offset: typing.Optional[int] = None)` or with more up to date syntax `def generate(offset: int | None = None)`

Comment: In any case, it isn't exactly clear to me what you are asking here. Can you elaborate on exactly the behavior you expect, maybe with some examples?

Comment: yes, you are right